# How to connect an Oracle server between two countries and maintain high speeds for read & write

Tags: networking, performance-tuning, oracle10g, oracle-11g

Our company has two branches, one in Malaysia and the other one in India. The problems occur when we try to share one of our Oracle environments to our branch in India; the connection is very slow, and we are looking for a way with have high speeds for both branches but our company doesn't want spend lots of money for new servers.

What is your suggestion? Right now we create one environment in the India branch & we connect from Malaysia.  Most of the time session will expire during applying the fixes.

How we can increase the speed & what is your suggestion for sharing one environment between two countries.

I suggested they hire a server between two county so speed will become higher but they didn't accept it because most of them are expensive....

Answer (score 2):

If the network connection between the two sites is too slow, your options in general would be to improve the speed of the network connection or to reduce the amount of traffic being sent over the network.  Improving the speed of the network connection would undoubtedly cost money.  If you have a particularly chatty application, you could potentially improve the networking layer to be more efficient.

If local users are doing mostly selects with relatively few updates and inserts, separate servers may improve the situation.  If you're generating redo more quickly than the network can transmit it, however, the two systems will drift further apart.  And you may need to make substantial changes to your application in order to allow it to work in a multi-master replication environment.

Comment: Much better than my just abandoned answer of "more bandwidth".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have leased WAN connections between the offices? If you do you could consider some sort of WAN acceleration appliance. We've had fairly good luck with [Riverbed](http://www.riverbed.com/us/solutions/wan_optimization/index.php) products for this purpose. You reduce bandwidth and hopefully Oracle will respond quicker too (Riverbed has Oracle specific WAN acceleration).